# how do I dump the content of a Response object from Tweepy?

Tags: json, rest, tweepy

I get a response object from Tweepy's client.get_tweet:

```
Response(data=<Tweet id=000 text='tweet string'>, includes={'users': [<User id=000 name=J username=j>]}, errors=[], meta={})

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tweet.py", line 41, in <module>
    print(tweets.json())
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'json'
```

but whatever I do to try and print the raw content of the Response, I can't get it done (as above). Ideally, I would just print it all as one big JSON.

I tried looping over response and printing each element, json()ing it all as I saw here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json

but nothing quite works. It either returns partial information, no information, or an error.

Comment: sorry, wrong comment here.